# How to resolve IntelliJ IDEA not knowing Python's print?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

While it knows all usual imports, for some reason IntellJ IDEA with the Python plugin claims an unknown reference for `print`. Since this seems to only apply to `print`, other solutions mentioned in similar questions (e.g. invalidating the cache) don't work. So,

> how to tell IntelliJ IDEA's Python plugin that `print` is a builtin?

Comment: Is your IDE configured with a python 3 interpreter while you are writing code in python 2 or vice versa ?

Comment: @bvidal It's both Python 3

Comment: I am having an issue similar to this 7 years after the fact. It didn't recognize isinstance, yet I can confirm that I have a system interpreter configured (Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs shows Python 3.10 and the debug console opens). Any ideas why this would be happening these days, @ElBert?
Actually, it also doesn't recognize "import json". I can run it fine in the debug console, but it's just not recognized for static analysis purposes

Comment: I think the fact my interpreter was installed for the current user only was f**king with it; Windows 11..... probably wasn't helping that. I uninstalled and reinstalled for all users and (after adding a System Interpreter reference) it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: @TwistedCode Good to know, thanks for the info. I think I had Python installed for the local user only back then as well

Answer (score -2):

```
from __builtin__ import print

print("Hello")
```

You can just import builtin modules.

Comment: Sure I can, but that is not necessary to create valid Python code and probably causes more confusion than it helps - "Why did he import `print` from `__builtin__`? Is this a different `print` than the usual one?". Also, I seem to remember one should use `builtins` instead, at least in Python3

Comment: yeah this seems to be missing the point.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.